# CSV File to Array without the last value

Tags: python, neural-network, dataset

So I'm pretty new to Python and the Neural Network Scene. I programmed a few Neural Networks(mostly CNN)but those were just some Test Projects. I finished them with a lot of help from tutorials etc. Now I'm trying to program a simple neural network that predicts the grade of students by some "indicators". The problem is that the "variables" aren't separated by column. I need to separate the indicators into a list of all indicators without the last one and a list with the last one but without the other stuff. I'm also pretty sure i need to transform "yes" and "no" into 1 and 0.

The DataSet: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/student+performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the csv data:

- Use **read_csv** to load the data into a dataframe. Specify semi-colon as the separator.
- Use the **columns** collection to adjust which columns you want to extract from the main dataframe
- Use **apply** to convert a column from yes\no to 1\0

Here is the top 5 rows of the csv file for reference:

```
school;sex;age;address;famsize;Pstatus;Medu;Fedu;Mjob;Fjob;reason;guardian;traveltime;studytime;failures;schoolsup;famsup;paid;activities;nursery;higher;internet;romantic;famrel;freetime;goout;Dalc;Walc;health;absences;G1;G2;G3
"GP";"F";18;"U";"GT3";"A";4;4;"at_home";"teacher";"course";"mother";2;2;0;"yes";"no";"no";"no";"yes";"yes";"no";"no";4;3;4;1;1;3;6;"5";"6";6
"GP";"F";17;"U";"GT3";"T";1;1;"at_home";"other";"course";"father";1;2;0;"no";"yes";"no";"no";"no";"yes";"yes";"no";5;3;3;1;1;3;4;"5";"5";6
"GP";"F";15;"U";"LE3";"T";1;1;"at_home";"other";"other";"mother";1;2;3;"yes";"no";"yes";"no";"yes";"yes";"yes";"no";4;3;2;2;3;3;10;"7";"8";10
"GP";"F";15;"U";"GT3";"T";4;2;"health";"services";"home";"mother";1;3;0;"no";"yes";"yes";"yes";"yes";"yes";"yes";"yes";3;2;2;1;1;5;2;"15";"14";15
```

Here is the code to parse the csv data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("student/student-mat.csv", sep=';')  # read csv
dfmain  = df[df.columns[:-3]]  # no grade columns
dfgrade = df[df.columns[-3:]]  # grade columns

for c in df.columns[16:24]:  # yes\no columns
   dfmain[c] = dfmain[c].apply(lambda x: 0 if str(x)=='no' else 1).astype(int) # no=0, yes=1

print(dfmain[df.columns[16:24]])  # yes\no columns
```

Output (yes\no columns)

```
     famsup  paid  activities  nursery  higher  internet  romantic  famrel
0         0     0           0        1       1         0         0       1
1         1     0           0        0       1         1         0       1
2         0     1           0        1       1         1         0       1
3         1     1           1        1       1         1         1       1
4         1     1           0        1       1         0         0       1
..      ...   ...         ...      ...     ...       ...       ...     ...
```

Comment: Worked thx for the help. Helped me in a lot of ways

Comment: Good to hear. Please mark the answer as accepted to remove the post from the "No Answer" list. Thanks,